# How do I control the BIOS using Synergy?

Tags: boot, synergy

How can I enter special parameters to a synergy controlled system to get into the BIOS or the like? For example, the "del" key causes some PCs to boot into the BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Synergy doesn't control the entire computer *magically* – it's only a Windows, Mac and Linux program and only starts working once the operating system has booted.